# Number of combinations with a max. of successively repeated characters

Tags: passwords

I would like to calculate the possible password combinations for a password that is 60 characters long, has the letters a-f and numbers 0-9. Also no character should repeat successively more than 7 times. Is there any way to calculate the possible combinations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would have approximately $60^{16}$ possible combinations, less if you want to reduce repeats.

Comment: Even tough the maximum amount of successive repeats per character should be 7?

Comment: That would reduce the number of combinations, but not by all that much.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $16^{60}$, not $60^{16}$.